# Who gets scheduled reminder emails?

Tags: scheduled-reminders

When scheduled email reminders go out for membership for an organization, which of the related individuals does the email go to?

I have searched but cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the right combination of words to google and found an answer here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34203.0