# Do I need to edit or delete action.cronjob.php to get Scheduled Reminders e-mails sent?

Tags: cron-job, scheduled-reminders

Using CiviCRM 4.6.11, Drupal 7. I've gone through all the steps to set up a couple of test scheduled reminders. I'm triggering the tests manually. I've enabled the Scheduled Job for sending scheduled reminders.

Yet, e-mails are not being sent.

Even though the [Managing Scheduled Jobs](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs) page says that action.cronjob.php is a deprecated bin script, is that bin script still installed with 4.6.11 and do I need to edit or delete it?

Comment: Joe - might it be  a case of there being an entry in civicrm_action_log already for that reminder/person? also note that a bug has been reported relating to scheduled reminders here - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8952/who-gets-scheduled-reminder-emails.

Comment: ps removed several of your tags as they seemed to distract from the key focus

Comment: Peter, thanks, but I'm not sure how multiple entries in civicrm_action_log would stop any e-mails from going out. Can you explain that?

Comment: Peter - so perhaps it's corruption in the civicrm_action_log table that's the cause

Comment: updated my link in comment above - oh it won't let me. i meant this jira issue updated my link in comment above

Comment: Peter, do you mean CRM-16880, still open in Jira?

Comment: Also looks like the issue might be related to CRM-17880 as well.

Comment: yes 17880 as reported in http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/scheduled-reminders-working-for-some-but-not-all